# Using GET request instead of POST one

Tags: post, get

The issue is that there is a form I want to fill. It's submitted via a POST request. But technically I can use only GET requests (pass an URL with GET parameters). And  I don't have access to a server where the site (with a form to fill) is located.

I've tried to use POST params in GET request, but it didn't work. The other thing that came to my mind was to send GET request to my own server, which will perform the desired POST request. But I need the request to be commited from my IP, but not from the server's one...

Can anybody give some piece of advice concerning solving this problem?

Comment: What server-side technology are you using?

Comment: How is the data being transmitted from point A to point B? What's done with the data that's posted? When you say "technically I can use only GET requests", what is technically preventing you from using POST?

Comment: Му server is running Apache, but the problem with IPs makes my server useless.

Comment: I can't use POST requests because all I have on client-side is browser's adress bar. Posted data are saved in a DB, if you meant this.

Answer (score 0):

Is this homework?  Seems odd that you wouldn't be able to use a POST.

Regardless,

The best way to do this would be to override the onclick event of your submit button; the JS function could poll for the fields you are looking to submit.  Then use encodeURIComponent() on the values to get them sent to your webserver correctly.

Here you would be able to load the new page with the get?element=value&.... request.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURIComponent.asp

Comment: It's not a homework :) The matter is that I don't have access to a source of a page where the form is located. But I want to give the link, submitting a form, to another person. And all that person has is a browser-like adress bar.

Comment: No worries; I think if you just override the onclick you can achieve what you are looking for. There are certain issues with mixing URL parameters and POST parameters (at least I know this is the case in Perl CGI) where if you get a POST, it will NOT parse out any of the GET parameters.  So you'll need to try this out on your server side to ensure that doing POST/GET will give the same result.

Comment: Sorry, probably I didn't formulate my question clearly enough. I DON'T have access to a server where the site (with a form to fill) is located. All I have is some other computer with Apache and other stuff (I have full access to it). Some other man has an address bar and wants to submit a form.

Comment: And, as I've written, GET with the same params doesn't work where POST does.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox allows you to turn an HTML form (either GET or POST) with at least one regular text input field into a search keyword bookmark, although I'm not sure how easy it is to import and export an individual bookmark from one copy of Firefox to another.

Comment: Unfortunately, there are no text fields... But nevertheless, thanks a lot, I'll ponder over this idea.

Comment: Well, it might still be possible to create a POST bookmark by editing places.sqlite outside of Firefox.